# Hölzel projection - prj.file

Tags: coordinate-system

Is there a prj-file-defintion available for the Hölzel-projection? (http://dl.maptools.org/dl/libproj4/manual.pdf#page=58, page 58)?

Comment: It should rather be on page 58, right?

Comment: yes, you are right, I will correct it to the right page now in my posting

Comment: John Snyder in Flattening the Earth, page 308, note 121, says that Philip Voxland determined that it's "essentially the same as Eckert V between 80N and S."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hölzel projection does not seem to be implemented in current GDAL and PROJ.

You get a list of valid projections of your installation with

```
proj -lp
```

and you can test every projection in GDAL with

```
gdalsrsinfo +proj=<name>
```

Following the hint of mkennedy, you can use EPSG:53011 Eckert V as well, with the WKT definition as .prj file:

```
PROJCS["Sphere_Eckert_V",
GEOGCS["GCS_Sphere",
 DATUM["D_Sphere",
 SPHEROID["Sphere",6371000,0]],
 PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
 UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
PROJECTION["Eckert_V"],
 PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],
 PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
 PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0],
 UNIT["Meter",1]]`
```

giving you this picture:

[image]

For the x values, both formulas given by Gerald Evenden have the same result, but y is scaled by 0.882 with Eckert V.

Comment: does this mean, that there can not exist a prj-file, if its not implemented in GDAL and PROJ?

Comment: @Kurt that's correct because a prj file (well-known text) includes a keyword that refers to the map projection algorithm.